VS Code remote SSH: Unable to connect to server
I left my VSCode ssh waiting for a password for a long time and then I closed the connection.
Next time I tried to ssh to it gets stuck on "Opening Remote".I had faced this one time before and deleted the .vscode/ and .vscode-server/ directories on the server side and tried again. That didn't work.
code version: 1.91.1
f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729
x64
Remote-ssh extension version: v0.113.1
log of Output terminal upon trying to connect:
[11:13:27.211] Log Level: 2
[11:13:27.219] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+vm-name.domain-name.com", attempt 1
[11:13:27.220] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[11:13:27.220] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[11:13:27.220] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:13:27.220] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[11:13:27.221] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[11:13:27.222] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[11:13:27.222] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[11:13:27.222] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[11:13:27.222] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[11:13:27.222] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[11:13:27.225] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[11:13:27.225] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[11:13:27.231] VS Code version: 1.91.1
[11:13:27.231] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.113.1
[11:13:27.232] win32 x64
[11:13:27.234] SSH Resolver called for host: vm-name.domain-name.com
[11:13:27.234] Setting up SSH remote "vm-name.domain-name.com"
[11:13:27.237] Using commit id "f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729" and quality "stable" for server
[11:13:27.240] Install and start server if needed
[11:13:29.691] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[11:13:29.695] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:13:29.695] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[11:13:29.697] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:13:29.697] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[11:13:29.698] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:13:29.698] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[11:13:29.700] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:13:29.700] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[11:13:29.908] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[11:13:29.913] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 50167 "vm-name.domain-name.com" bash
[11:13:29.916] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:13:30.964] > username@vm-name.domain-name.com's password:]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:13:30.965] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:13:30.965] Showing password prompt
[11:13:38.329] Got password response
[11:13:38.329] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***************"
[11:13:38.395] > 
[11:13:38.982] > find: No match.
[11:13:39.110] > find: No match.
[11:13:39.243] > find: No match.

I completely removed VScode on client side and tried again but this is still an issue.
I also see that ./vscode-server is not created on the server side.
I tried selecting the >Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host option but that also doesn't help.
I wish to get VSCode to ssh to my server again.

try to end pending ssh connection from client machine.

Resolved it.
Issue was that I removed the complete vscode-server directory. Instead I should have removed only vscode-server/bin and/or /data
